# Deleting pages in a word document using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a .docx template I use containing tables with placeholder names that I replace with data from a .xlsx file using openpyxl and python-docx. For example I have a "tool" placeholder that is replaced with the contents of cell A1 in the .xlsx.
Its a dumb workaround, but thats life when I cant get the business to use .xlsx to begin with.

The template is 126 pages, and I use anything from 1-126 depending on the part being documented. Currently I remove the unused pages manually. Is there a way to remove for example pages 10 through 126 using python?

All the pages are identical to start with, so another solution would be to generate the correct amount of pages at the beginning, I've tried various ways of doing that, but can never get the logo picture to copy correctly.

Comment: I think a Word document in composed internally of paragraphs. The number of pages depends on the page size. If your document has page breaks, I think something could be done to remove things between the i-th page break and the j-th page break. Another option could be having different templates with just the content that you need.

Comment: @Hernán Multiple templates is a good option if I cant find a better way of doing it, thanks for that, it didn't cross my mind for some reason. Its going to be a bit of a chore to set up 126 of them. If the solution for deleting pages is to loop through paragraphs then multiple templates might be a better option as It'll run much faster for the 99% of times where I only use <10 pages.